# Reading file in c from Linux to Windows 8 yields strange format

Tags: c, windows, debian, readfile

**The Question (Summary)**
Why is it when I read a file the first two characters are printed as question marks before the first actual character of the text file is captured? Then every second `fgetc` appears to blank space however the .txt file does not have that space.

**E.g.** for test.txt the format is

```
2,123.5,12312.02,12.3,222.35
```

if I loop an `fgetc` and print each character (to check the code snippet go to AP1 further down).

```
for i = 0, c = ?

for i = 1, c = ?

for i = 2, c = 2

for i = 3, c =

for i = 4, c = ,

for i = 5, c =

for i = 6, c = 1

for i = 7, c =

for i = 8, c = 2

for i = 9, c =
```

Why does it do this? I just want to read the file!

**The details**
So what I am trying to do is read a file called test.txt on a Windows 8 laptop which is networked to a debian 8 computer. I think it is a Peer-to-Peer connection over a VAR11N-300. The c program is executed on the Debian computer. In the background SAMBA is running (although I'm not sure how this works I just followed another post and it worked so I was happy) to connect the two computers (let me know if i'm talking smack).

My initial thought was that I could use fscanf to read the file because it was in a consistent format unfortunately it wouldn't work properly as it would include the two ? ? characters at the beginning and then think that it was at the end of the file. *That is why I took out feof(fptr) from the code snipped in AP1*. Then I changed tactic and decided to use fgetc to retrieve each character.

The file format is as following

integer (letting me know how many coordinates there are),x1,y1,x2,y2 etc

Let me know if you need to know anything else to answer my question.

**AP1 Code Snippet**

```
char c;

int i=0;

do

{

  c = fgetc(fptr);

  printf("for i = %d, c = %c\n",i,c);

  i++;

} while(i<10)
```

Comment: Highlight your code and press ctrl+k

Comment: Your file is UTF-16 with a BOM.

Comment: P.S. if your test file was created with a text editor, ignore it and work with a file actually created with the software that will be interacting with your program.